# How to avoid passing object in the same class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, object

My Class looks like:

```
class MyDBClass extends SQLite3{

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('/path_of_file');
        }

        public function saveArticle($product, $dbObject){
            try{
                $title = sqlite_escape_string(strip_tags($product['title']));
                $productInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Products (Title) VALUES (:title)";
                $query = $dbObject->prepare($productInsertQuery);
                $query->bindValue(':title', $title, SQLITE3_TEXT);   
                $result = $query->execute();
            }
            Catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling it another class like :

```
$this->dbObject->saveProduct($product, $this->dbObject);
```

How I can avoid to pass $this->dbObject inside the same class its orginating from, can I pass any reference or do something else? Or is it OK to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is not OK. What you have is a complete disaster. Also, please learn hoe prepared statements actually work.

Comment: why dont you answer it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->prepare($articleInsertQuery);
```

might help. As you now don't need `$dbObject`, you can drop it from the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Use factory pattern to get your DB object instead of creating it every time you need. You can create a new factory class which can store instance(s) of the DB objects initialized and returned every time you need. The DB objects may be retrieved from a pool of already created ones, for example.